# we need to know at $z=0$ ,$f(z)={e^z+1\over e^z-1}$ has a

Tags: complex-analysis

we need to know at $z=0$ ,$f(z)={e^z+1\over e^z-1}$ has a

1. removable singularity
2. a pole
3. essential singularity
4. residue is $2$

for removable singularity we need $\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=0$ but here this is not the case so $1$ is false, clearly $2$ is true, also $3$ is false, I have calculated that $\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=2$ so residue is $2$ at simple pole $z=0$ am I right in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you are right.
2. Yes, you are right.
3. Yes, you are right.
4. Yes, the residue is 2.

I don't have too much to add unfortunately.